# Common FormatDate function for different date formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Am formatting the Date Format in JavaScript with the below code

```
function changeDateFormat(date) {
    var fromJSON = new Date(parseInt(date.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
    return fromJSON.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + fromJSON.getDate() + "/" + fromJSON.getFullYear() + " " + fromJSON.getHours() + ":" + fromJSON.getMinutes();
    }
```

i have 2 scenarios where i call the function  with 2 diferent parameters

```
if date = "/Date(1374145967638)/"  am getting the correct o/p
if date = "7/18/2013 4:28:52 PM"   am getting Jan 01 1970
```

Is there a way i can write a common function in javascript/Jquery to handle both the dates ?

Am looking for an option **without any JQUERY Plugins**.

Thanks

Comment: I know you said no jQuery plugins, but does that exclude any external scripts?  **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** is quite fantastic for date time conversions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first create a javascript `Date` object from date string then format it in what ever way you want.

ex:

```
var date = new Date("7/18/2013 4:28:52 PM");
```

then you can use different date class methods and format the string manually.